# Issue Mocking Multiple Items on Path Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have code that looks like the following:

```
@patch.object(Path, "__init__", return_value=None)
@patch.object(Path, "exists", return_value=True)
@patch.object(Path, "read_text", return_value="FAKEFIELD: 'FAKEVALUE'")
def test_load_param_from_file_exists(self, *mock_path):
    expected_dict = YAML.safe_load("FAKEFIELD: 'FAKEVALUE'")
    return_dict = load_parameters("input", None)
    self.assertTrue(return_dict["FAKEFIELD"] == expected_dict["FAKEFIELD"])
```

and deep in the code of `load_parameters`, the code looks like this:

```
file_path = Path(parameters_file_path)
if file_path.exists():
    file_contents = file_path.read_text()
    return YAML.safe_load(file_contents)
```

Right now, I have to break it up into two tests, because I cannot seem to get a single mock object that allows me to switch between "file exists" and "file doesn't". Ideally, I'd be able to do a single test like this:

```
@patch.object(Path, "__init__", return_value=None)
@patch.object(Path, "exists", return_value=False)
@patch.object(Path, "read_text", return_value="FAKEFIELD: 'FAKEVALUE'")
def test_load_param_from_file(self, mock_path, *mock_path_other):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        load_parameters("input", False)

    mock_path.read_text.return_value = "FAKEFIELD: 'FAKEVALUE'"
    expected_dict = YAML.safe_load("FAKEFIELD: 'FAKEVALUE'")

    return_dict = load_parameters("input", None)

    self.assertTrue(return_dict["FAKEFIELD"] == expected_dict["FAKEFIELD"])
```

To be clear, the above doesn't work because each of those patched objects get instantiated differently, and when the `Path` object in the `load_parameters` method gets called, `exists` is mocked correctly, but  `read_text` returns no value.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to patch multiple methods on a single object or class?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be:

```
def test_load_param_from_file_exists(self):

    # Adjust the name as necessary
    mock_path = Mock()
    mock_path.exists.return_value = True
    mock_path.read_text.return_value = '{"FAKEFIELD": "FAKEVALUE"}'

    with patch("Path", return_value=mock_path):
        return_dict = load_parameters("input", None)

    self.assertTrue(return_dict["FAKEFIELD"] == 'FAKEVALUE')
```

Configure a `Mock` to behave like you want `file_path` to behave, then patch `Path` to return that object when it is called.

(I removed the code involving the environment variable, since it wasn't obvious the value matters when you patch `Path`.)

Comment: Interesting! I guess I misunderstood Mock - this does look really elegant. I'll check the answer later today!

Comment: Hmm.. ok, when I do this, I get - Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tests/test_main.py", line 293, in AttributeError: type object 'Path' has no attribute 'rsplit' –